# Pull elements by attributes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to pull only the ones with flex display out of 10 child elements

`document.querySelectorAll('.DOMDivCont[display="flex"]')`

When I try this it returns empty array

Comment: Does your element looks like this: `<div class="DOMDivCont" display="flex">`?

Comment: yes. this is similar mine

Answer (score 0):

This is only possible if the element has a inline display=flex, but you want to select by style

`document.querySelectorAll('.DOMDivCont[style*="disyplay: flex"]')`

so you get every DOMDivCont with inline style that contains flex

But the downsites are

1. it will also find flex-inline etc
2. its not working if you write it like "disyplay:flex"
3. its only for inline styles

If you want to select them by computed styles, then you have to do something like

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.DOMDivCont').forEach(element => {
  console.log(getComputedStyle(element).display);
})
```